# Gradiant of XAY with respect to A

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find the gradient of the following function with respect to A?
$$
F(A) = X^T \cdot A \cdot Y
$$
Where X and Y are mx1 vectors and A is mxm matrix

Comment: Hint: $F$ is a linear map

Answer (score 1):

Writing

$F(A + \Delta A) = X^T A Y + X^T \Delta A Y$,

we see that

$F(A + \Delta A) - F(A) = X^T \Delta A Y$;

the error terms vanish exactly as they would for a plain old vanilla-flavored scalar function $f(x) =  ax$:

$f( x + \Delta x) - f(x) = a(x + \Delta x) - ax = a \Delta x$:

thus the derivative is a constant linear map; we have

$DF(\Delta A) = X^T (\Delta A) Y$.

The derivative  of any linear map is a constant and equal to the map itself.  For more info., see this Wikioedia page:  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus.

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To add to Robert's answer slightly, note $X^T\Delta A Y$ is the inner product (matrix component wise) of $XY^T$ with $\Delta A$ so if you vectorize the gradient, the $i,j$ term of the gradient is $X_i Y_j$ ($i$ is row and $j$ is column)

Comment: thanks for the clarifying annendum!  Cheers!